# Remove list of columns from a DataFrame when some do not exist

Tags: python, pandas

For a pandas DataFrame, I can drop any existing columns using

```
data.drop([col], axis=1)
```

If I want to drop several columns, as long as they all exist in the data, I can drop them all at once using

```
data.drop(list_of_cols, axis=1)
```

How can I drop several columns if some do not exists.  I want to make sure none of the columns in my list are in the data.

Is there a standard way to drop a list of columns ignoring those that do not exist instead of throwing `KeyError`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As simple as

```
df.drop(columns=cols, errors='ignore')
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest method I found for removing several columns, when some are not in the DataFrame, is to use list comprehension.

```
col_exists = [col for col in list_of_cols if col in data.columns]
new_data = data.drop(col_exists, axis=1)
```

An alternative methods that was slightly slower (but mangled the column order) used set operations.

```
col_keep = set(data.columns) - set(list_of_cols)
new_data = data[col_keep]
```

And of course there is the slow loop option.

```
for col in list_of_cols:
    try:
        data = data.drop([col], axis=1)
    except KeyError:
        pass
```

Comment: The issue is covered by the existing documentation on drop. I don't see why this needed to be a self-answered question that doesn't use the existing API that already addressed it

Comment: Try inside your first method do the columns list this way: ```col_exists = set(list_of_cols).intersection (set(data.columns))``` should be a bit faster.

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski that is a nice alternative.  For my actual use case it was slightly slower, at 28.4 us with the set intersection compared to only 15.7 us with the list comprehension.  That said, I think the set intersection method is more understandable to newer Python programmers.